# Tensorfolow error when running %%bash cd /content/models/research python -m pip install

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, roboflow

I am following a roboflow tutorial named "Roboflow-TensorFlow2-Object-Detection" on google colabs. But when I run

```
cd /content/models/research
python -m pip install .
```

I get the following error

```
CalledProcessError: Command 'b'cd /content/models/research\npython -m pip install .\n'' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Any idea why ? and how do I fix it ? appreiciate  your kind assistance.